# Open Prezi inside the android app

Tags: javascript, android, webview, prezi

Anybody knows how to open [Prezi Presentation](https://prezi.com/ftv9hvziwqi2/coca-cola-company/) inside the android app or if anyone knows how to add [given code](http://prezi.github.io/prezi-player/getit.html) in webView please tell me.

**What i have tried so for**

```
initializeWebView();

String html, path = "mkg9y_pl1cxd";
html = "<script src=\"http://prezi.github.io/prezi-player/lib/PreziPlayer/prezi_player.js\"></script><div id=\"player-api-intro\"></div>    <script>    var player = new PreziPlayer('player-api-intro', {  'preziId' : '"
                + path + "',    height: '" + screenHeight + "',          width: '" + screenWidth
                + "'    }); try{                        player.on(PreziPlayer.EVENT_STATUS, function(event) {           if (event.value == PreziPlayer.STATUS_CONTENT_READY) {                          var no_of_slides=player.getStepCount();             var user_sec="
                + 10
                + ";                var  new_sec=   user_sec/no_of_slides;                      setInterval('player.flyToNextStep();', (new_sec * 1000));           }       });     }catch(e){} </script></script>";

String mimeType = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
mainWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null",html, mimeType, encoding, "");   

private void initializeWebView()    
    {
        String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
        mainWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.Wv);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
        mainWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
        mainWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
        mainWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
        mainWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mainWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mainWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        mainWebView.stopLoading();
        mainWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

        mainWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    }
```

i am getting follwoing error in log cat

```
11-30 14:12:48.725: E/Web Console(1582): Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL null from frame with URL https://prezi.com/player/?oid=mkg9y_pl1cxd&explorable=0&controls=0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

but i am unable to load presentation in webView. Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong. Thanks for any help.